# Cannot perform HTTP calls if app is woken up by geofence event

Tags: ios, ios13, swift5, geofencing

We implemented geofencing in our app. It seems to work just fine as long as the app is not killed (swiped away by the user)

If force closed, the geofences do trigger as I can see in my logging in `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)` but when I try to do http traffic, no matter if I use alamofire or another approach (see below) it seems to be stuck.

This is the code

```
private func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
    return UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        log.error("#geofence expiration handler was executed")            
    })
}

private func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskID)
}    


func sendEvent(eventType: EventType, id: String) {
    let taskID = beginBackgroundUpdateTask()        

    log.info("#geofence sending event: \(eventType.rawValue) id: \(id) with background task id: \(taskID)")

   //... stripped out

    sendRequest(url: personUrlWithParameters, params: params, taskID: taskID, eventType: eventType)

}


func sendRequest(url: String, params: [String : Any], taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier, eventType: EventType) {        

    let url = URL(string: url)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "PUT"

    log.debug("#geofence params: \(params)")

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        log.error(error.localizedFailureReason!)
        request.httpBody = nil
        return
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("Something", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

//// THIS LINE is never reached ///

            log.debug("#geofence PUT responseCode \(resp.statusCode)")                       

            if resp.statusCode == 200 {
                log.info("#geofence event: \(eventType.rawValue) id: \(taskID.rawValue) succeeded")

            } else {
                log.error("#geofence error occured - must notify user about it: \(eventType.rawValue) id: \(taskID.rawValue) failed with response code: \(resp.statusCode)")
            }

            log.info("#geofence stop task with id: \(taskID)")
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskID)

            return
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

As you can see we start a backgroundTask and even end it properly.

The completion handler of the http call is never reached, see comment inside code.
What's interesting is, that the expiration handler is also not reached, no matter how long you wait.
As I can only test this while the app is force closed, there is no possibility to debug it in the debugger.

What am I doing wrong?
What's different to a normal app launch compared to a launch due to .location?  (see code below) Why can I not use HTTP?
To clarify again, the code above is working smoothly if the app is not killed!
*(edit: No, it's not 100% reliable. Being open in the task switcher does not necessarily mean it will work. It seems to depend upon the time the app was not used. If too much, it won't work although still being open in the task switcher)*
Help much appreciated

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        initLogger()

        log.warning("#lifecycle didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")          

        if let keys = launchOptions?.keys {
            if keys.contains(.location) {                   
                    log.info("Started because of location!")                      
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            log.info("Regular App start (NOT because of location)")
        }
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Yes! By making use of DispatchGroups to synchronize the treads
Unfortunately I didn't find the time to update this thread and I did not think that it arouse anyone's interest

Comment: When the event is triggered by the system I schedule a local notification that the geofence could not be updated on the servers side (pessimistic assumption). If all goes well I cancel that notification. I did not find a solution to keep retrying all over in the background, so the user must manually open the app in case a geofence transmission failed. Hope I could help?
If you find a solution to keep retrying until it succeed, let me know

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try that